# lupa not working on mac OSX 10.9.5

Tags: macos, lua, lupa

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lupa import *
>>> lua=LuaRuntime()
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lupa/_lupa.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lupa/_lupa.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    11436 trace trap  python
```

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall lupa. Then install again with:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/bin/lua" pip install lupa==1.3 --no-binary :all:
```

NOTE: Above path to lua binary is default one on El Capitan when installing lua via brew (brew install lua). You might have to change path to your lua binary if it's installed somewhere else, e.g. to usr/bin/lua.